# auto increment admission number when a jsp page is opened

Tags: jsp, servlets

I did increment of admission number on basis of visit count of the page....but every time server is restarted the admission number gets initialised.This is an application form. What I need is admission number auto incremented and displayed on the form every time a user opens the form
I am new to java an jsp please help.here is code:

```
<p>Admission for

<input type= "radio" name="whichclass" id="wc1"  value="daycare">

<label for="wc1">DayCare</label>

<input type="radio" name="whichclass" id="wc2" value="nursery">

<label for="wc2">Nursery</label>

<input type="radio" name="whichclass" id="wc3" value="pp1" >

<label for="wc3">PP1</label> 

<input type="radio" name="whichclass" id="wc4" value="pp2">

<label for="wc4">PP2</label></p>

    <% 
        //Get creation time

        Date createTime =  new Date(session.getCreationTime());




        // Get last access time of this web page

        Date lastAccessTime = new Date(session.getLastAccessedTime());

        String title= "Welcome back";   


        Integer visitCount = new Integer(0);

        String visitCountKey= new String("vistCount");

        //Create a variable for Admission number

        Integer adNumber = new Integer(20150);

        String adNumberKey = new String("adNumber");



        //Check if user is new

        if(session.isNew())

        {
            String title1 = "Welcome to Application form";

            session.setAttribute(visitCountKey, visitCount);

            session.setAttribute(adNumberKey, adNumber);
        }

        visitCount= (Integer)session.getAttribute(visitCountKey);

        visitCount= visitCount + 1;


        adNumber= (Integer)session.getAttribute(adNumberKey);

        adNumber = adNumber+1;

        session.setAttribute(visitCountKey,visitCount);

        session.setAttribute(adNumberKey, adNumber);

        %>

<p>Admission number    <input type="text" name="adNum"  value= <%=adNumber %> /></p>
```

Comment: Store `visit count` into db

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your question is that,

> Blockquote

you want to track the number of times your page is being browsed and generate a form number everytime (auto-incrementing), however your problem is that you whenever the server is restarted the number gets re-initialized.

> Blockquote

First of all you are using session to store the number. Session is specific for each user. Don't use it because for different users, different adNumbers will be there in their specific sessions. So you might end up having two different users with same adNumber.

A better approach would be using [ServletContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) which is per JVM. So that there would be only one adNumber for all the users (ignoring concurrency and distributed system).

However, with ServletContext also the count will reset once you restart the server.

A better approach would be using ServletContext in conjunction with a database or a file based system. Every time the count is incremented you can store the value in database or in a file if a DB isn't available.

When the server will get restarted you can check if an attribute named "adNumberKey" exists in the context or not, if not then read the value from the database or file based source and load it into the context object.

Hope it helps!!

Comment: explanation is very useful...i'll use servletContext